# Synchronizing Git-svn from previously migrated git

Tags: git, svn

SVN to GIT migration was done by previously (not by me).

More revisions were checked in to SVN, which I now need to synchronize to GIT.

I know the access url for SVN and also got the git copy by doing

git clone

Now how do I get the changes from svn. How will I know until which revision the SVN was migrated to GIT and how to resume from there.
I can see find the commits(originally made on svn) on the GIT branch but I do not see "git svn-id"
There is no "svn-remote" section in the .git/config.
If I try to add by 
"git svn init "
and do 
"git svn fetch" it seems to fetch the whole repository again.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to `SVN repository`. You can install [SubGit](http://www.subgit.com/) into project directory.

`$ subgit install path/to/your/svn/repostiory`

`SubGit` will take care of all the synchronization and it will be performed automatically (triggered by SVN and Git hooks). It will sync all the branches (though you can configure its behavior).

Comment: If there's no access to the SVN repository, one can still install SubGit by specifying `--svn-url` option, see SubGit [book](http://www.subgit.com/remote-book.html#10) for details.

Comment: I dont want to keep the synchronization ongoing since I plan to discontinue svn.
This is one time synchronization, and also I am merging 2 projects into one, so would prefer to do this without a tool.
My basic issue is how can I fetch revisions from svn which were committed after the initial migration effort. e.g. svn had till rev. 100 which is right now migrated to GIT. but now I want to synchronize from rev 101-120 to GIT. There is no svn metadata to help with this sync.